# Segfault process id and core dump process id are different. Why?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, segmentation-fault

In the Linux message file, I notice that a segfault is reported for process 14947, but I did not get the core dump for process 14947, instead I got 14069.core.(Its generated time matches the time the segfault is hit).

Then I use gdb and find:-

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 14947]
[New process 26131]
[New process 26130]
[New process 26129]
[New process 26128]
[New process 14945]
[New process 14842]
[New process 14726]
[New process 14598]
[New process 14069]
```

When I run "info thread", I get:-

```
(gdb) info thread
10 process 14069  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
9 process 14598  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
8 process 14726  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
7 process 14842  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
6 process 14945  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
5 process 26128  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
4 process 26129  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
3 process 26130  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
2 process 26131  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
* 1 process 14947  0x006a8300 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
```

So here goes my questions:-

1. Why the coredump file name does not match the segfault process id in the message file?
2. I think the coredump is for a particular process, why there are so many info like "[New process 26130]" here ?
3. why "info thread" will display the info for process, not thread?

Thanks!

Plus: My OS is RHEL5.

Comment: I don't really know, but perhaps it has to do with Linux threads being processes with their own id's....least that's the way I've always remembered it being.

Comment: Show us the program that produced this segmentation fault.

Comment: @Eric Leschinski Sorry, Eric, I can't pasted the code here, and there is no symbol available for the binaries. what's worse, the stack is also corrupted. Not sure how to allocate the part of code introduce this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, kernel threads are simply light-weight processes (processes where the virtual memory  is marked as shared with the parent process rather than marked as copy-on-write), and hence the process IDs that you see listed are the same as the thread IDs. This is just a guess, but probably the ID for the core is the same as the thread that handled the signal, which might not be the same as the main thread.